# Using Regular Expression to extract word in a string in C

Tags: c, regex

I'm trying to extract a small substring from a string of words in c. I did it in a previous program written in python using this code:

```
out_block = "".join(re.findall(r'.FT off(.*?).FT on',finaltext,re.DOTALL))
```

The code extracts all the characters in between `.FT off` and `.FT on`and passes it to `out_block` as a string.

I wanted to know how to do the same using regular expressions but in C

How would I convert this code to a C code that does the exact same thing?

Comment: Which regex library are you using?

Comment: That's not what that regex does, btw.

Comment: @melpomene but it ran and did exactly that. It extracted the words in between the bracket words as a list, I joined the list and passed it to out_block as a string, it worked exactly like that

Comment: I'm using regex.h

Comment: `.` matches any character. If you want to match `".FT off"`, you need `\.FT off`.

Comment: Drew, What have you tried so far in C? Post the code that did not work with you.

Comment: @melpomene yeah I thought that too but the code worked fine so I just left it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicly you do this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <regex.h>

regex_t finder;
if (0 != regcomp(&finder, "regex-string", 0)) { error handling }
```

You might need to adjust your regex string above.

After that you can do any number of times:

```
regmatch_t match[N_MATCH];
if (0 == regexec(&finder, "haystack", N_MATCH, match, 0)) {
    process matches
} else {
    no match
}
```

Clean up using `regfree` and get error messages (in `regcomp`) using `regerror`.

For more details, consult man page regex(3).

Comment: Okay so, "regex-string" in this case would be the pattern, and "haystack" would be the string we're searching in, is that right?

Comment: yea [just spam to get this posted]